# How can I fadeOut a div when I scroll down to the hole div, It will not show again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout, slidedown

I am looking to implement a feature in which a notification displays via `slideDown` at the top of the page on a button (or other element) click, and then hides via `fadeOut` when it is scrolled out of view. This functionality is similar to what happens when clicking "How It Works" on [airbnb's website](https://www.airbnb.com).

For clarity, the following is the functionality that I am looking for:

1. Click a specified element to make the notification display
2. Notification slides into view at the top of the page and window automatically scrolls to the top
3. User scrolls down the page and the notification element fades out as soon as it is scrolled out of view

Does anyone have any idea how this can be implemented?

Comment: Research [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It's a free JavaScript library that will let you do this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation they use is pretty long and has a lot of functions returning functions, but the following is a quick pseudo-code description of what you need to do:

1. Create a `click` handler for the element you want to use as your "show button" that shows your "notification" when clicked. Note that my implementation jumps to the top of the page. In your implementation, you should change this to the smooth scrolling technique of your choice. **UPDATE: I checked against Airbnb's site again and even without the smooth scrolling my implementation visually functions the same as theirs.**

   ```
   var $notification = $(".notification");

   $(document).on("click", ".show-button", function() {
       $notification.slideDown(); //can use whatever effect you want here, or just .show()
       window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to top of page
   });
   ```
2. Next, create a `scroll` handler for the `window` that checks to see if the page has been scrolled down below the height of the "notification" (in other words, check to see if the notification is no longer in view). If it is not in view anymore, hide the element and update the scroll position so the page doesn't jump. Note that with my implementation, the page may jump in slower browsers because I'm not using smooth scrolling. However, when you add smooth scrolling the effect will look natural.

   ```
   $(window).on("scroll", function() {
       var notificationHeight = $notification.outerHeight(); //may be able to cache this or calculate outside the handler for reuse, depending on implementation
       var currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (currentScrollY > notificationHeight) {
           $notification.hide(); 

           //update the scroll browser scroll position
           var updatedScrollY = currentScrollY - notificationHeight;
           window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, updatedScrollY);
       }
   });
   ```
3. If we are looking to use an animation/effect to hide the "notification," then we need to update our `scroll` handler from the above. Looking at the current code, notice that we use `$notification.hide()` which instantly removes the element from the document. As such, the space consumed by the notification is not included when we compute the updated scroll position. However, if you use an animation/effect, like `.fadeOut`, the element's `display` property is not set to `none` until the animation COMPLETES, though the script execution continues immediately after the animation BEGINS (i.e. immediately after it is called). As such, the new scroll position will be calculated and applied before the notification is removed from the flow, causing the page to appear to jump to the top, with the notification in full or nearly full view. In order to get around this, we need to hold off on the execution of the the code to update the scroll position until the animation/effect finishes. We can do this easily moving the code for updating the scroll position into the animation/effect method's callback.

   ```
   $(window).on("scroll", function() {
       var notificationHeight = $notification.outerHeight(); //may be able to cache this or calculate outside the handler for reuse, depending on implementation
       var currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (currentScrollY > notificationHeight) {
           //can use whatever effect you want, but must pass scroll position update code in callback to prevent page jump, if not using .hide()
           $notification.fadeOut(function () {
             //update the scroll browser scroll position
             var updatedScrollY = currentScrollY - notificationHeight;
             window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, updatedScrollY);
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   **NOTE: Since we cannot see the element, we shouldn't be using an animation/effect, like `fadeOut`, to hide the notification. Adding the effect would merely add unnecessary overhead, since the element is not in view when it is hidden. However, I have included this step because the OP specifically mentioned using `fadeOut` for hiding the notification. I will include examples for both in the demo.**
4. Since I'm a fan of performance and we don't need handle the `scroll` event of `window` unless the "notification" is actually being shown, let's move our `scroll` handler binding into a function, and add a namespace and `.off` call so that we can unbind it without affecting other handlers.

   ```
   //binds the scroll handler we created in step 2 to the window
   function bindScrollHandlerForNotification() {
       $(window).on("scroll.checkHideNotification", function() {
           var notificationHeight = $notification.outerHeight(); //may be able to cache this or calculate outside the handler for reuse, depending on implementation
           var currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

           if (currentScrollY > notificationHeight) {
               //can use whatever effect you want, but must pass scroll position update code in callback to prevent page jump, if not using .hide()
               $notification.fadeOut(function() {
                   //update the scroll browser scroll position
                   var updatedScrollY = currentScrollY - notificationHeight;
                   window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, updatedScrollY);

                   //unbind the handler since the notification is hidden
                   $(window).off("scroll.checkHideNotification");
               });
           }
       });
   }
   ```
5. Now that we have a function to bind our handler, let's update the `click` handler from step 1 to call the function to bind our `scroll` handler.

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".show-button", function() {
       $notification.slideDown(); //can use whatever effect you want here, or just .show()
       window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to top of page
       bindScrollHandlerForNotification();
   });
   ```

### FINAL IMPLEMENTATIONS AND DEMOS

#### Using .fadeOut() to hide notification

```js
var $notification = $(".notification");

//listen for our show button to be clicked
$(document).on("click", ".show-button", function() {
  $notification.slideDown(); //can use whatever effect you want here, or just .show()
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to top of page
  bindScrollHandlerForNotification();
});

//binds the scroll handler we created in step 2 to the window
function bindScrollHandlerForNotification() {
  $(window).on("scroll.checkHideNotification", function() {
    var notificationHeight = $notification.outerHeight(); //may be able to cache this or calculate outside the handler for reuse, depending on implementation
    var currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (currentScrollY > notificationHeight) {
      //can use whatever effect you want, but must pass scroll position update code in callback to prevent page jump, if not using .hide()
      $notification.fadeOut(function() {
          //update the scroll browser scroll position
          var updatedScrollY = currentScrollY - notificationHeight;
          window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, updatedScrollY);

          //unbind the handler since the notification is hidden
          $(window).off("scroll.checkHideNotification");
      });
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.page-container {
  height: 5000px;
}
.notification {
  display: none;
  padding: 75px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background: #009afd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.main-content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="notification"><span class="notification-content">Test Notification</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-block">
      <button type="button" class="show-button">Show Notification</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Using .hide() to hide notification

```js
var $notification = $(".notification");

//listen for our show button to be clicked
$(document).on("click", ".show-button", function() {
  $notification.slideDown(); //can use whatever effect you want here, or just .show()
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to top of page
  bindScrollHandlerForNotification();
});

//binds the scroll handler we created in step 2 to the window
function bindScrollHandlerForNotification() {
  $(window).on("scroll.checkHideNotification", function() {
    var notificationHeight = $notification.outerHeight(); //may be able to cache this or calculate outside the handler for reuse, depending on implementation
    var currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (currentScrollY > notificationHeight) {
      //can use whatever effect you want, but must pass scroll position update code in callback to prevent page jump, if not using .hide()
      $notification.hide();
      
      //update the scroll browser scroll position
      var updatedScrollY = currentScrollY - notificationHeight;
      window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, updatedScrollY);

      //unbind the handler since the notification is hidden
      $(window).off("scroll.checkHideNotification");
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.page-container {
  height: 5000px;
}
.notification {
  display: none;
  padding: 75px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background: #009afd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.main-content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="notification"><span class="notification-content">Test Notification</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-block">
      <button type="button" class="show-button">Show Notification</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the messy code, but it gets the point across.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slideDiv").click(function() {
    $("#banner").show().animate({height: "300px"}, 0);
  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    var link = $("#banner");
    var offset = link.offset();
    
    var top = offset.top;
    var bottom = top + link.outerHeight();
   
    if(scroll > bottom) {
      link.hide().css({height: 0});
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#banner {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" id="slideDiv">test</a>
    
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas blandit sapien quis augue blandit faucibus. Nullam ac purus cursus turpis tempus blandit. Maecenas quis diam turpis. Integer metus ligula, pulvinar nec arcu et, tempor lobortis nunc. Integer in nunc in mi bibendum bibendum. Sed consectetur congue nibh id egestas. Quisque maximus, eros vitae mattis tempus, magna sem varius turpis, non accumsan ex velit nec mauris. Duis cursus commodo mi commodo facilisis. Donec turpis ante, gravida aliquet molestie porttitor, semper nec dolor.

Maecenas sed porta dui. Quisque vulputate tortor sed varius maximus. Ut eget mi eleifend, finibus ligula vel, malesuada diam. Etiam ultrices magna vitae condimentum sagittis. Maecenas tempor pellentesque lectus, eget ultricies ante maximus vestibulum. Phasellus molestie placerat dolor sit amet fringilla. In elit enim, vulputate quis varius eu, egestas nec nulla. Nulla congue eros vel nibh molestie sagittis. Mauris faucibus tellus at justo porta tincidunt. Vestibulum convallis ex et sapien placerat finibus. Nulla aliquam luctus tortor at dapibus. Phasellus semper orci eget magna egestas laoreet. Maecenas ut ligula egestas, lobortis enim efficitur, sollicitudin odio.

Phasellus porttitor mauris ut erat commodo, at bibendum massa ullamcorper. Nunc facilisis est eget sagittis gravida. Nulla eget augue semper, accumsan leo ac, sollicitudin tortor. In mi tortor, porta ac libero pretium, mollis fringilla massa. Maecenas auctor nibh ligula, vel varius nisl porta eget. Cras consectetur aliquet commodo. Aenean in tincidunt augue, non finibus mauris. Pellentesque rhoncus iaculis leo. Integer pellentesque tellus at tincidunt bibendum. Nullam vehicula pretium malesuada. Praesent in nulla posuere, auctor risus sed, volutpat ligula.

Nunc consectetur at ante eu pharetra. Nullam at augue hendrerit, laoreet erat vitae, maximus massa. Donec purus felis, varius lacinia ex vel, gravida aliquet arcu. Phasellus a ipsum nec odio convallis porttitor. Phasellus molestie lorem at aliquam sagittis. Aliquam sed ultricies nunc. Pellentesque vitae tincidunt ante, sit amet condimentum felis. Proin imperdiet, tellus eu vehicula interdum, libero augue sagittis nibh, in luctus neque turpis ac enim. Fusce iaculis semper lacus, non condimentum neque cursus in. Suspendisse rhoncus lectus eleifend purus consectetur, eu placerat felis tempus. Fusce turpis tortor, scelerisque ullamcorper tellus ac, iaculis viverra risus. Aenean varius mollis nisi, at euismod tellus. Integer ullamcorper ipsum eget nisi rhoncus finibus. Quisque eget commodo ex, pretium vehicula dui. Integer sed feugiat tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Nunc risus elit, rutrum ac nisi in, gravida vestibulum nunc. Duis sodales blandit nisl, in condimentum nisi facilisis at. Nulla eleifend pulvinar libero, et congue sem molestie ut. Sed sollicitudin, neque quis iaculis vehicula, sapien dolor ornare nibh, nec placerat diam dui a leo. Nullam ut semper eros. Etiam vitae quam consequat, molestie ligula id, tincidunt ipsum. Proin ullamcorper malesuada faucibus. Nunc molestie in neque quis ultricies. Proin non diam non sapien tristique viverra.

Aenean sagittis metus eget mi ullamcorper accumsan. Maecenas in ex at arcu porta pellentesque gravida ut arcu. Nulla mattis sagittis erat eu pulvinar. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec rhoncus metus vel nulla eleifend, eu lacinia augue aliquam. Fusce id nisi quis tortor ultrices egestas non gravida dui. Aliquam volutpat aliquam felis, ac commodo felis venenatis nec. Duis interdum, est a sollicitudin commodo, turpis mauris consectetur nunc, ut eleifend quam ex ut ex. Phasellus et diam eget turpis placerat egestas vehicula at nibh. Phasellus feugiat nulla ac nisi vestibulum, a aliquet metus dictum. Vestibulum nec sapien vitae leo mollis ultrices ac sed sem.

Pellentesque vitae tincidunt ante, sit amet condimentum felis. Proin imperdiet, tellus eu vehicula interdum, libero augue sagittis nibh, in luctus neque turpis ac enim. Fusce iaculis semper lacus, non condimentum neque cursus in. Suspendisse rhoncus lectus eleifend purus consectetur, eu placerat felis tempus. Fusce turpis tortor, scelerisque ullamcorper tellus ac, iaculis viverra risus. Aenean varius mollis nisi, at euismod tellus. Integer ullamcorper ipsum eget nisi rhoncus finibus. Quisque eget commodo ex, pretium vehicula dui. Integer sed feugiat tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc risus elit, rutrum ac nisi in, gravida vestibulum nunc. Duis sodales blandit nisl, in condimentum nisi facilisis at. Nulla eleifend pulvinar libero, et congue sem molestie ut. Sed sollicitudin, neque quis iaculis vehicula, sapien dolor ornare nibh, nec placerat diam dui a leo. Nullam ut semper eros. Etiam vitae quam consequat, molestie ligula id, tincidunt ipsum. Proin ullamcorper malesuada faucibus. Nunc molestie in neque quis ultricies. Proin non diam non sapien tristique viverra. Aenean sagittis metus eget mi ullamcorper accumsan. Maecenas in ex at arcu porta pellentesque gravida ut arcu. Nulla mattis sagittis erat eu pulvinar. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec rhoncus metus vel nulla eleifend, eu lacinia augue aliquam. Fusce id nisi quis tortor ultrices egestas non gravida dui. Aliquam volutpat aliquam felis, ac commodo felis venenatis nec. Duis interdum, est a sollicitudin commodo, turpis mauris consectetur nunc, ut eleifend quam ex ut ex. Phasellus et diam eget turpis placerat egestas vehicula at nibh. Phasellus feugiat nulla ac nisi vestibulum, a aliquet metus dictum. Vestibulum nec sapien vitae leo mollis ultrices ac sed sem.

Pellentesque vitae tincidunt ante, sit amet condimentum felis. Proin imperdiet, tellus eu vehicula interdum, libero augue sagittis nibh, in luctus neque turpis ac enim. Fusce iaculis semper lacus, non condimentum neque cursus in. Suspendisse rhoncus lectus eleifend purus consectetur, eu placerat felis tempus. Fusce turpis tortor, scelerisque ullamcorper tellus ac, iaculis viverra risus. Aenean varius mollis nisi, at euismod tellus. Integer ullamcorper ipsum eget nisi rhoncus finibus. Quisque eget commodo ex, pretium vehicula dui. Integer sed feugiat tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc risus elit, rutrum ac nisi in, gravida vestibulum nunc. Duis sodales blandit nisl, in condimentum nisi facilisis at. Nulla eleifend pulvinar libero, et congue sem molestie ut. Sed sollicitudin, neque quis iaculis vehicula, sapien dolor ornare nibh, nec placerat diam dui a leo. Nullam ut semper eros. Etiam vitae quam consequat, molestie ligula id, tincidunt ipsum. Proin ullamcorper malesuada faucibus. Nunc molestie in neque quis ultricies. Proin non diam non sapien tristique viverra. Aenean sagittis metus eget mi ullamcorper accumsan. Maecenas in ex at arcu porta pellentesque gravida ut arcu. Nulla mattis sagittis erat eu pulvinar. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec rhoncus metus vel nulla eleifend, eu lacinia augue aliquam. Fusce id nisi quis tortor ultrices egestas non gravida dui. Aliquam volutpat aliquam felis, ac commodo felis venenatis nec. Duis interdum, est a sollicitudin commodo, turpis mauris consectetur nunc, ut eleifend quam ex ut ex. Phasellus et diam eget turpis placerat egestas vehicula at nibh. Phasellus feugiat nulla ac nisi vestibulum, a aliquet metus dictum. Vestibulum nec sapien vitae leo mollis ultrices ac sed sem.
Pellentesque vitae tincidunt ante, sit amet condimentum felis. Proin imperdiet, tellus eu vehicula interdum, libero augue sagittis nibh, in luctus neque turpis ac enim. Fusce iaculis semper lacus, non condimentum neque cursus in. Suspendisse rhoncus lectus eleifend purus consectetur, eu placerat felis tempus. Fusce turpis tortor, scelerisque ullamcorper tellus ac, iaculis viverra risus. Aenean varius mollis nisi, at euismod tellus. Integer ullamcorper ipsum eget nisi rhoncus finibus. Quisque eget commodo ex, pretium vehicula dui. Integer sed feugiat tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc risus elit, rutrum ac nisi in, gravida vestibulum nunc. Duis sodales blandit nisl, in condimentum nisi facilisis at. Nulla eleifend pulvinar libero, et congue sem molestie ut. Sed sollicitudin, neque quis iaculis vehicula, sapien dolor ornare nibh, nec placerat diam dui a leo. Nullam ut semper eros. Etiam vitae quam consequat, molestie ligula id, tincidunt ipsum. Proin ullamcorper malesuada faucibus. Nunc molestie in neque quis ultricies. Proin non diam non sapien tristique viverra. Aenean sagittis metus eget mi ullamcorper accumsan. Maecenas in ex at arcu porta pellentesque gravida ut arcu. Nulla mattis sagittis erat eu pulvinar. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec rhoncus metus vel nulla eleifend, eu lacinia augue aliquam. Fusce id nisi quis tortor ultrices egestas non gravida dui. Aliquam volutpat aliquam felis, ac commodo felis venenatis nec. Duis interdum, est a sollicitudin commodo, turpis mauris consectetur nunc, ut eleifend quam ex ut ex. Phasellus et diam eget turpis placerat egestas vehicula at nibh. Phasellus feugiat nulla ac nisi vestibulum, a aliquet metus dictum. Vestibulum nec sapien vitae leo mollis ultrices ac sed sem.</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

The jQuery checks if the scrollbar y-position is greater than the y-position of the bottom of the expanded div.

EDIT: Modified it to make it smoother and used the internal SO snippet tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries to do this such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

With it, this is what you will need to do:

- Create a 'click()' function to make your div slide down
- Attach that function to some element (like a button in my example)
- Create a 'scroll()' function to see when the scroll reaches a certain height
- Make your div 'fadeOut()' when it does

JS

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#slideme").slideDown("slow");
});

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>100 /* Insert height here */){
        $("#slideme").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

You can find the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qrdttrL1/1/

Comment: I don't believe a hardcoded height would work on responsive sites or if the div adjusts to the content. It would be better to get the bottom offset of the div before fading away.

Comment: I think he was just showing that for the example (ergo the comment), but I agree that it should be noted that a hard-coded height should be avoided for this implementation. In addition to flexibility, when the `.scrollTop > 100` returns true, that means that the scroll position is past `100` and the page will jump. Changing to comparison operator to `>=` is also insufficient, since the returned value will almost never be the whole integer (which is why most implementations just use `>`). **Moral of the story:** To avoid page jump, subtract from the current to get the new scroll position.